# Scheduling Forefront Endpoint Protection with SCCM 2007

Tags: sccm, microsoft-forefront

I just started using SCCM 2007 in our network (replacing the old IT assistant) and I was wondering how to schedule a scan for a group of computers using Forefront Endpoint Protection.
What would be the instructions for creating a scheduled virus scan for a number of computers? Thank you.